# Drop idle connection in Spring Boot / hikari

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I want a database connection that has gone idle to be dropped once its maxLifetime has been reached.

How can we do this in spring boot/hikari? Is this achieved with these 2 properties?

idleTimeout
maxLifetime

How can I check that idle connections are actually being dropped? Any logs I can activate?

What should be the ideal values?

Comment: Enable logging, ideal values depends on your system, there are no hard rules.

Answer (score 0):

- read Hikari documentation
- check DB activity via SQL (there you can see all transaction statistics)
- add logging
- try locally with Postgres in Docker